# I failed to apply onClickListiner to an ImageButtons in a Listview

Tags: java, android, listview

I need to open phone app when I click on the callButton and to internt a map location when I click mapButton, PS: the adapter got filled correctly but it did nothing when I click on any objects

here is my Adapter codes

```
package com.voyage_eg.voyage;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class StoresAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Stores>  {

    public StoresAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Stores> stores) {
        super(context, 0, stores);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
//        super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        View listItemView = convertView;

        if(listItemView == null) {
            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.dist_layout, parent, false);
        }

        Stores currentStore = getItem(position);

        Stores currentStores = getItem(position);

        TextView storeName = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.storeName);
        storeName.setText(currentStores.getStoreName());

        ImageView storeImage = (ImageView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.storeImage);
        storeImage.setImageResource(currentStores.getStoreImageResourceId());

        ImageButton callButton = (ImageButton) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.callButton);
        callButton.setImageResource(currentStores.getStoreMobileButton());

        ImageButton mapButton = (ImageButton) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.mapButton );
        mapButton.setImageResource(currentStores.getStoreAddressButton());

        return listItemView;
    }
}
```

below is the Activity that holds the listview

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.distribution_points);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    cartPadgeNumber=findViewById(R.id.cartPadgeNumber);

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Create an ArrayList of AndroidFlavor objects

    final ArrayList<Stores> stores = new ArrayList<Stores>();
    stores.add(new Stores("El Badry Serag Mall", R.drawable.badry_logo, R.drawable.ic_call_black_24dp, R.drawable.ic_directions_black_24dp));
    stores.add(new Stores("El Badry Maadi", R.drawable.badry_logo, R.drawable.ic_call_black_24dp, R.drawable.ic_directions_black_24dp));
    stores.add(new Stores("El Badry Hurghada", R.drawable.badry_logo, R.drawable.ic_call_black_24dp, R.drawable.ic_directions_black_24dp));
    stores.add(new Stores("Dose Mart Nasr City", R.drawable.dose_nasr_logo, R.drawable.ic_call_black_24dp, R.drawable.ic_directions_black_24dp));
    stores.add(new Stores("Dose Mart Heliopolis", R.drawable.dose_hel_logo, R.drawable.ic_call_black_24dp, R.drawable.ic_directions_black_24dp));
    stores.add(new Stores("Dose Mart Maadi", R.drawable.dose_maadi_logo, R.drawable.ic_call_black_24dp, R.drawable.ic_directions_black_24dp));
    stores.add(new Stores("ADAMS", R.drawable.adams_logo, R.drawable.ic_call_black_24dp, R.drawable.ic_directions_black_24dp));
    stores.add(new Stores("First Exit Maadi", R.drawable.first_exit_logo, R.drawable.ic_call_black_24dp, R.drawable.ic_directions_black_24dp));
    stores.add(new Stores("First Exit New Cairo", R.drawable.first_exit_logo, R.drawable.ic_call_black_24dp, R.drawable.ic_directions_black_24dp));
    stores.add(new Stores("Mahala Vape Club", R.drawable.mahala_logo, R.drawable.ic_call_black_24dp, R.drawable.ic_directions_black_24dp));
    stores.add(new Stores("El Kot Vape El Zamalik", R.drawable.kot_logo, R.drawable.ic_call_black_24dp, R.drawable.ic_directions_black_24dp));
    stores.add(new Stores("Ghost Vape Heliopolis", R.drawable.ghost_logo, R.drawable.ic_call_black_24dp, R.drawable.ic_directions_black_24dp));
    stores.add(new Stores("Ghost Vape", R.drawable.ghost_logo, R.drawable.ic_call_black_24dp, R.drawable.ic_directions_black_24dp));
    stores.add(new Stores("The Hub El Mohandeseen", R.drawable.hub_logo, R.drawable.ic_call_black_24dp, R.drawable.ic_directions_black_24dp));
    stores.add(new Stores("The Hub El Dokki", R.drawable.hub_logo, R.drawable.ic_call_black_24dp, R.drawable.ic_directions_black_24dp));
    stores.add(new Stores("The Hub El Embaba", R.drawable.hub_logo, R.drawable.ic_call_black_24dp, R.drawable.ic_directions_black_24dp));
    stores.add(new Stores("Mashro3 Mazah", R.drawable.mashro3_mazag_logo, R.drawable.ic_call_black_24dp, R.drawable.ic_directions_black_24dp));
    stores.add(new Stores("Cloud House", R.drawable.cloud_house_logo, R.drawable.ic_call_black_24dp, R.drawable.ic_directions_black_24dp));
    stores.add(new Stores("Cloud Cafe & Restaurant", R.drawable.cloud_cafe_logo, R.drawable.ic_call_black_24dp, R.drawable.ic_directions_black_24dp));
    stores.add(new Stores("King Vape", R.drawable.king_logo, R.drawable.ic_call_black_24dp, R.drawable.ic_directions_black_24dp));
    stores.add(new Stores("City Clouds", R.drawable.city_logo, R.drawable.ic_call_black_24dp, R.drawable.ic_directions_black_24dp));
    stores.add(new Stores("Fog Vape", R.drawable.fog_logo, R.drawable.ic_call_black_24dp, R.drawable.ic_directions_black_24dp));
    stores.add(new Stores("O2 Vape", R.drawable.o2_logo, R.drawable.ic_call_black_24dp, R.drawable.ic_directions_black_24dp));
    stores.add(new Stores("Zag Vape", R.drawable.zagvap_logo, R.drawable.ic_call_black_24dp, R.drawable.ic_directions_black_24dp));
    stores.add(new Stores("Awel Abbas 1", R.drawable.awel_abas_logo, R.drawable.ic_call_black_24dp, R.drawable.ic_directions_black_24dp));
    stores.add(new Stores("Awel Abbas 2", R.drawable.awel_abas_logo, R.drawable.ic_call_black_24dp, R.drawable.ic_directions_black_24dp));
    stores.add(new Stores("Roma Store October City ", R.drawable.roma_logo, R.drawable.ic_call_black_24dp, R.drawable.ic_directions_black_24dp));
    stores.add(new Stores("Roma Store El Haram ", R.drawable.roma_logo, R.drawable.ic_call_black_24dp, R.drawable.ic_directions_black_24dp));
    stores.add(new Stores("Miami Vape", R.drawable.miami_logo, R.drawable.ic_call_black_24dp, R.drawable.ic_directions_black_24dp));

    StoresAdapter adapter = new StoresAdapter(this, stores);

    final ListView storesListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.stores_listView);
    storesListView.setAdapter(adapter);

    storesListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                Stores storeItem = stores.get(position);
//   here where my two buttons clicks should be added //             
}
            });

    }
```

here is my Custom Class

```
package com.voyage_eg.voyage;

public class Stores {

    private int mStoreImageResourceId;
    private String mStoreName;
    private int mStoreAddressButton;
    private int mStoreMobileButton;
//    private String mStoreCall;
//    private String mStoreMap;

    public Stores(String storeName, int storeImageResourceId, int storeAddressButton, int storeMobileButton) {

        mStoreName = storeName;
        mStoreImageResourceId = storeImageResourceId;
        mStoreAddressButton = storeAddressButton;
        mStoreMobileButton = storeMobileButton;
//        mStoreMap = storeMap;
//        mStoreCall = storeCall;
    }

    public String getStoreName() {
        return mStoreName;
    }

    public int getStoreImageResourceId() {
        return mStoreImageResourceId;
    }

    public int getStoreAddressButton() {
        return mStoreAddressButton;
    }

    public int getStoreMobileButton() {
        return mStoreMobileButton;
    }
//
//    public String getStoreCall() {
//        return mStoreCall;
//    }
//
//    public String getStoreMap() {
//        return mStoreMap;
//    }


}
```

here is the layout xml that holds the objects of the adapter

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/storeImage"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/storeName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
        android:fontFamily="@font/denk_one"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/callButton"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ripple_effect"
        android:backgroundTint="#ca983c"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/mapButton"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ripple_effect"
        android:backgroundTint="#ca983c"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Fail ? Not really! you did not set the listener . Whats the question here ?

Comment: How to set it . Can you guide me please . I've been debugging this for 24 hrs with no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All what you have to do is to handle separately the click on each button with creation an interface on your adapter

Store Adapter

```
    public class StoresAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Stores> {


    OnclickListener mListener = null  ;


    public interface OnclickListener {

        void onMapButtonClick(int position);
        void onCallButtonClick(int position);
    }


    public StoresAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Stores> stores, OnclickListener listener) {
        super(context, 0, stores);
        mListener = listener ;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
//        super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        View listItemView = convertView;

        if(listItemView == null) {
            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.dist_layout, parent, false);
        }

        Stores currentStore = getItem(position);

        Stores currentStores = getItem(position);

        TextView storeName = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.storeName);
        storeName.setText(currentStores.getStoreName());

        ImageView storeImage = (ImageView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.storeImage);
        storeImage.setImageResource(currentStores.getStoreImageResourceId());

        ImageButton callButton = (ImageButton) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.callButton);
        callButton.setImageResource(currentStores.getStoreMobileButton());

        ImageButton mapButton = (ImageButton) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.mapButton );
        mapButton.setImageResource(currentStores.getStoreAddressButton());

        mapButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mListener.onMapButtonClick(position);
            }
        });

        callButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mListener.onCallButtonClick(position);
            }
        });

        return listItemView;
    }
}
```

In your Activity you have to change intialization of your adapter to this

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.distribution_points);

            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

            cartPadgeNumber=findViewById(R.id.cartPadgeNumber);

            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            // Create an ArrayList of AndroidFlavor objects

            final ArrayList<Stores> stores = new ArrayList<Stores>();
            stores.add(new Stores("El Badry Serag Mall", R.drawable.badry_logo, R.drawable.ic_call_black_24dp, R.drawable.ic_directions_black_24dp));
            stores.add(new Stores("El Badry Maadi", R.drawable.badry_logo, R.drawable.ic_call_black_24dp, R.drawable.ic_directions_black_24dp));
            stores.add(new Stores("El Badry Hurghada", R.drawable.badry_logo, R.drawable.ic_call_black_24dp, R.drawable.ic_directions_black_24dp));
            stores.add(new Stores("Dose Mart Nasr City", R.drawable.dose_nasr_logo, R.drawable.ic_call_black_24dp, R.drawable.ic_directions_black_24dp));
            stores.add(new Stores("Dose Mart Heliopolis", R.drawable.dose_hel_logo, R.drawable.ic_call_black_24dp, R.drawable.ic_directions_black_24dp));
            stores.add(new Stores("Dose Mart Maadi", R.drawable.dose_maadi_logo, R.drawable.ic_call_black_24dp, R.drawable.ic_directions_black_24dp));
            stores.add(new Stores("ADAMS", R.drawable.adams_logo, R.drawable.ic_call_black_24dp, R.drawable.ic_directions_black_24dp));
            stores.add(new Stores("First Exit Maadi", R.drawable.first_exit_logo, R.drawable.ic_call_black_24dp, R.drawable.ic_directions_black_24dp));
            stores.add(new Stores("First Exit New Cairo", R.drawable.first_exit_logo, R.drawable.ic_call_black_24dp, R.drawable.ic_directions_black_24dp));
            stores.add(new Stores("Mahala Vape Club", R.drawable.mahala_logo, R.drawable.ic_call_black_24dp, R.drawable.ic_directions_black_24dp));
            stores.add(new Stores("El Kot Vape El Zamalik", R.drawable.kot_logo, R.drawable.ic_call_black_24dp, R.drawable.ic_directions_black_24dp));
            stores.add(new Stores("Ghost Vape Heliopolis", R.drawable.ghost_logo, R.drawable.ic_call_black_24dp, R.drawable.ic_directions_black_24dp));
            stores.add(new Stores("Ghost Vape", R.drawable.ghost_logo, R.drawable.ic_call_black_24dp, R.drawable.ic_directions_black_24dp));
            stores.add(new Stores("The Hub El Mohandeseen", R.drawable.hub_logo, R.drawable.ic_call_black_24dp, R.drawable.ic_directions_black_24dp));
            stores.add(new Stores("The Hub El Dokki", R.drawable.hub_logo, R.drawable.ic_call_black_24dp, R.drawable.ic_directions_black_24dp));
            stores.add(new Stores("The Hub El Embaba", R.drawable.hub_logo, R.drawable.ic_call_black_24dp, R.drawable.ic_directions_black_24dp));
            stores.add(new Stores("Mashro3 Mazah", R.drawable.mashro3_mazag_logo, R.drawable.ic_call_black_24dp, R.drawable.ic_directions_black_24dp));
            stores.add(new Stores("Cloud House", R.drawable.cloud_house_logo, R.drawable.ic_call_black_24dp, R.drawable.ic_directions_black_24dp));
            stores.add(new Stores("Cloud Cafe & Restaurant", R.drawable.cloud_cafe_logo, R.drawable.ic_call_black_24dp, R.drawable.ic_directions_black_24dp));
            stores.add(new Stores("King Vape", R.drawable.king_logo, R.drawable.ic_call_black_24dp, R.drawable.ic_directions_black_24dp));
            stores.add(new Stores("City Clouds", R.drawable.city_logo, R.drawable.ic_call_black_24dp, R.drawable.ic_directions_black_24dp));
            stores.add(new Stores("Fog Vape", R.drawable.fog_logo, R.drawable.ic_call_black_24dp, R.drawable.ic_directions_black_24dp));
            stores.add(new Stores("O2 Vape", R.drawable.o2_logo, R.drawable.ic_call_black_24dp, R.drawable.ic_directions_black_24dp));
            stores.add(new Stores("Zag Vape", R.drawable.zagvap_logo, R.drawable.ic_call_black_24dp, R.drawable.ic_directions_black_24dp));
            stores.add(new Stores("Awel Abbas 1", R.drawable.awel_abas_logo, R.drawable.ic_call_black_24dp, R.drawable.ic_directions_black_24dp));
            stores.add(new Stores("Awel Abbas 2", R.drawable.awel_abas_logo, R.drawable.ic_call_black_24dp, R.drawable.ic_directions_black_24dp));
            stores.add(new Stores("Roma Store October City ", R.drawable.roma_logo, R.drawable.ic_call_black_24dp, R.drawable.ic_directions_black_24dp));
            stores.add(new Stores("Roma Store El Haram ", R.drawable.roma_logo, R.drawable.ic_call_black_24dp, R.drawable.ic_directions_black_24dp));
            stores.add(new Stores("Miami Vape", R.drawable.miami_logo, R.drawable.ic_call_black_24dp, R.drawable.ic_directions_black_24dp));

           final ListView storesListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.stores_listView);


        StoresAdapter adapter = new StoresAdapter(this, stores, new StoresAdapter.OnclickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapButtonClick(int position) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "this is click on map "+position,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCallButtonClick(int position) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "this is click on call "+position,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        final ListView storesListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.stores_listView);
        storesListView.setAdapter(adapter);



    }

}
```

Hope this is helpful :)

Comment: your solution is so simple and informative and working like a charm  :) i can't thank your enough my friend ..

Answer (score 0):

you make interface to handle click event in list view define below interface in storeAdapter ..

```
onCallButtonClick onCallButtonClick;
```

onCallMapClick onCallMapClick;
    public interface onCallButtonClick{
        void onCall(); // if you want pass any data when you need
    }
    public interface onCallMapClick{
        void onMap();// if you want pass any data when you need
    }

```
public void setOnCallButtonClick(StoresAdapter.onCallButtonClick onCallButtonClick) {
    this.onCallButtonClick = onCallButtonClick;
}

public void setOnCallMapClick(StoresAdapter.onCallMapClick onCallMapClick) {
    this.onCallMapClick = onCallMapClick;
}
```

after that when click on button in adapter used below code..

```
callButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onCallButtonClick.onCall();
        }
    });
    mapButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onCallMapClick.onMap();
        }
    });
```

after that when you bind adpater in list view used below code for getting click event ..

```
    adapter.setOnCallButtonClick(new StoresAdapter.onCallButtonClick() {
        @Override
        public void onCall() {

        }
    });
```

Comment: tested your answer and yes it is working , thanks a lot for your kind answer

Answer (score 0):

You should add `onClickListener` inside the adapter `getView()` method after you initialize the button

```
callButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
   { 
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) 
       {
           // Your code that you want to execute on this button click
       }

   });
```

And do not forgetto make your both `listview` item and `button` `clickable`, do this.

make `ListView` focusable `android:focusable="true"`

Button not focusable in your custom listview item `android:focusable="false"`